# I want to ask date from User in DD/MM/YYYY format and I want to insert '/' automatically after DD or MM or YYYY

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am writing one small program in which I need to ask date from user in DD/MM/YYYY format in C using printf() :

```
char str[20];
printf("Enter Date in DD/MM/YYYY " __/__/____);
fgets(str,20,stdin);
```

//But the problem is

1. If I am taking string and user is going to type date without slash, than there is no way to find the exact date format , for example , 112016, now there is no way to know its 1 Jan 2016 or Nov 2016
2. I have tried with Backslash '\b' and with int data type but its not giving the exact result as there is no way to preserve my slashes
3. Data type is not the problem as I can change by using logics but the most important thing is slashes,

Is there any way to ask date in that kind of format, what I simply need is backslash in between the DD/MM/YYYY, I believe there must be, give some advice me on that, thanks in advance ?

and yeah, there are so many articles based on this ,and I already read those but they are not giving me what I'm looking for.

I think I need to elaborate my problem more.. I just want to ask Enter date : and more specific what I am looking for is after date (date must consist 2 integer digits) '/' pops up on screen and the rest I'll do myself.
So basically a validation method which looks for 2 digits and if there are not error(I can handle that) but if there are 2 digits than '/'(or any other character) will come on screen automatically.
I have looked into (time.h) and its doing the kinda same thing but with system time. Thanks!!!

Comment: Why don't you take three different inputs?

Comment: What's wrong with the standard funfctions? They also handle the system locale - The US date-format is far from being universally accepted.

Comment: There are at least couple of ways. You can either ask for day, month and year separately or parse the input and reject it if there are no slashes.

Comment: I can but It would look awkward like type date , next line Month and than year.. I want to do this in one line .. @GMichael

Comment: what's with Standard function ? @Olaf

Comment: @DeveshPratap look at `strptime` (http://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime) or `getdate` (http://linux.die.net/man/3/getdate)

Comment: @GMichael: They are **not** standard functions.

Comment: @Olaf What do you mean?

Comment: @GMichael: They are not in the standard.

Comment: @Olaf **Standard** is a too common word. For example, both function are defined by X/Open and POSIX standards. Not everything is in the language standard

Comment: @Olaf Not standard as in "C standard", but the `strptime()` is in "X/Open Portability Guide Issue 4,  Version 2 (“XPG4.2”)"

Comment: @GMichael , thanks for help, it seems that the Internet website I've been using it doesn't have these functions and one more time I've realized the importance of System Programming or Advance C. thanks

Comment: @GMichael Can't find `getdate()` anywhere. Is that a Linux-only thing?  Ah, found it on Mac OS X as well, but not on OpenBSD.

Comment: @Kusalananda I cannot see it, too. But `strptime` does exist on OpenBSD: http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man3/strptime.3

Comment: Cant you use fullstops `.` while taking in date to separate day month and year?

Comment: I can but the thing is how, the problem will remain the same if the user ain't going to type '.' , both are characters , can you tell me the logic ? @CherubimAnand

Comment: @GMichael: There is no POSIX tag. Linux is not standardized, nor **was** X/Open an officially accepted standardisation organisation.. But there is a C tag. So it is very clear what standard I'm talking about.

Comment: @Kusalananda: Please state the ISO, IEC, IEEE (or any other international standardisation organisation) number of that document. Also please point me to where the text states OP works in accordance with that document. There is also no tag.

Comment: @Olaf IEEE Std 1003.1, 2013 Edition, defines `strptime()`. We don't know that the OP works on such a system, that's true.

Comment: @Kusalananda: I know about POSIX. I meant the document you mentioned: "X/Open Portability Guide Issue 4, Version 2 (“XPG4.2”)". Anyway, I still did not get an answer to where the question invokes the impression user works on a compliant system (or at least one which provides the functions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to ask date from User in DD/MM/YYYY format and I want to insert
>   '/' automatically after DD or MM

It's unclear if you ever got the answer you were looking for. You can do what you describe above in C, but it requires putting the keyboard in *raw-unbuffered* mode so you can capture and respond to each key as it is input. In order to put the keyboard in *raw-unbuffered* mode, you want to (1) save the current keyboard setting with `tcgetattr` and then (2) set the appropriate values for *raw-unbuffered* mode in a `struct termios` variable to pass to `tcsetattr` which actually sets the new keyboard attributes. (the functions are in `termios.h`)

```
/* set keyboard in raw-unbufered mode, saving current mode in old */
struct termios *setkbmode (struct termios *new, struct termios *old)
{
    if (tcgetattr (0, old)) {   /* save orig settings   */
        fprintf (stderr, "setkbmode() error: tcgetattr failed.\n");
        return NULL;
    }   /* copy old to new */
    memcpy (new, old, sizeof (struct termios));

    new->c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);  /* new kbd flags */
    new->c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
    new->c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
    if (tcsetattr (0, TCSANOW, new)) { /* set new mode */
        fprintf (stderr, "setkbmode() error: tcgetattr failed.\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    return new;
}
```

When done, you simply reverse the process and pass your original saved keyboard attributes to `tcsetattr` returning the keyboard to its prior *buffered* configuration.

```
/* restore original keyboard mode */
struct termios *restorekbmode (struct termios *mode)
{
    /* reset original keyboard  */
    if (tcsetattr (0, TCSANOW, mode)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "restorekbmode() error: tcsetattr failed.\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    return mode;
}
```

The remainder is simply implementing logic that responds to user entry of digits and then providing a `/` separator visually to the user. The digit characters are captured in an character array `buf` up to a maximum of `9` chars (`8 + nul-terminating char`). To keep indexing straight and allow minimal `backspace` editing keeping a second string that contains all digits and the `/` characters makes it easier to keep the editing straight when the user is using the `backspace` key. Take a look at the example below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <termios.h>

struct termios *setkbmode (struct termios *new, struct termios *old);
struct termios *restorekbmode (struct termios *mode);

enum { MAXC = 9, MAXS = 11};

int main (void) {

    char buf[MAXC] = "",
         str[MAXS] = "";
    int c = 0;
    struct termios old, new;
    size_t idx = 0, stx = 0, sz = MAXC;

    setkbmode (&new, &old); /* set kbd in raw-unbufered mode */

    printf ("\n enter date (DD/MM/YYYY -- '/' are automatic): ");
    while ((c = getchar ()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
    {
        if (idx + 1 < sz && '0' <= c && c <= '9') { /* if valid digit */
            putchar (c);
            buf[idx++] = str[stx++] = c;
            if (idx == 2 || idx == 4) { putchar ('/'); str[stx++] = '/'; }
        }
        if (idx > 0 && c == 127) {      /* if backspace */
            putchar (0x8);
            putchar (' ');
            putchar (0x8);
            if (str[stx - 1] != '/')    /* handle '/' separator */
                buf[--idx] = 0;
            str[--stx] = 0;
        }
    }
    buf[idx] = 0;           /* nul-terminate both strings    */
    str[stx] = 0;
    restorekbmode (&old);   /* restore original kbd settings */

    printf ("\n buf  : %s\n", buf);
    printf (" str  : %s\n\n", str);

    return 0;
}

/* set keyboard in raw-unbufered mode, saving current mode in old */
struct termios *setkbmode (struct termios *new, struct termios *old)
{
    if (tcgetattr (0, old)) {   /* save orig settings   */
        fprintf (stderr, "setkbmode() error: tcgetattr failed.\n");
        return NULL;
    }   /* copy old to new */
    memcpy (new, old, sizeof (struct termios));

    new->c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);  /* new kbd flags */
    new->c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
    new->c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
    if (tcsetattr (0, TCSANOW, new)) { /* set new mode */
        fprintf (stderr, "setkbmode() error: tcgetattr failed.\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    return new;
}

struct termios *restorekbmode (struct termios *mode)
{
    /* reset original keyboard  */
    if (tcsetattr (0, TCSANOW, mode)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "restorekbmode() error: tcsetattr failed.\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    return mode;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/getchar_fmtdate

 enter date (DD/MM/YYYY -- '/' are automatic): 31/09/2016
 buf  : 31092016
 str  : 31/09/2016
```

See if this is what you were looking for, if not let me know and let me know if you have an questions.

Comment: It's working Sir. Thank you for this great answer. I don't have any questions despite IDK when I'll become that much good in this C language. :(

Comment: Glad it helped. C takes time to learn -- for everyone, even longer to learn well. No other language (aside from assembly) gives you the low-level control that C does. With hardware-level control, you can appreciate there will be a bit more to learn with C. However, learning C is time will spent and will give you a better understanding of programming, regardless of what language you are working in. Good luck with your coding. If this, or any other answer, was the most helpful, you need to select the answer by clicking the check in the top-left to indicate your question was answered.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by using a `sscanf()` function for assigning the date, month and year(which you get from the user) to separate variables like this:

```
fgets(string,100,stdin);
sscanf(string,"%d %d %d",&date,&month,&year);
```

Now you have the values of date, month and year assigned in separate variables.

For printing it with slashes just use the printf statement as below

```
printf("%d/%d/%d",date,month,year);
```

NOTE: 
This method wont work if the user doesn't leave spaces in between the date, month and year.

Comment: Sir, I dont use gets() , but thanks , my problem remains the same as there you mentioned spaces and I am asking for slashes.

Comment: `gets` was removed from C11 for good reason. Do NOT use `gets`

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to read a string from the user, then parse that string

```
int year, month, day;
char userinput[1000];
if (!fgets(userinput, sizeof userinput, stdin)) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
int check = parsedate(userinput, &year, &month, %day);
if (check != 0) {
    // deal with parsing error
}
```

And the function `parsedate()` would be something like

```
int parsedate(const char *input, int *y, int *m, int *d) {
    // if no / in input return 1;
    // if input has few digits return 2;
    // if input has negative numbers return 3;
    // if input has symbols return 4;
    // ... ... ...
    // if input month > 12 return 42;
    // ...
    *y = 2016; // get year from input
    *m = 6;    // get month from input
    *d = 21;   // get day from input
    return 0; // indicate success
}
```

Comment: well what if user just typed 102016 ? Thanks

Comment: 102016 looks like too few digits. The parser would return the appropriate error code.

Answer (score 0):

> what I am looking for is after date (date must consist 2 integer digits) '/' pops up on screen

You cannot do that with plain Standard C or even POSIX.

One available library that allows you to do that is [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html) (or see the [man pages](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html)).

For example, just a basic user interface snippet without special characters (backspace, escape, Fkeys, ...), validation, or error checking:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <curses.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int ch, k;

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    initscr();
    cbreak();
    noecho();
    nonl();
    intrflush(stdscr, FALSE);
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);

    k = 0;
    printw("Enter date: __ (DAY)\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b");
    do {
        ch = getch();
        if (isdigit((unsigned char)ch)) {
            printw("%c", ch);
            k++;
        } else {
            beep();
        }
    } while (k < 2);

    k = 0;
    printw("/__ (MONTH)\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b");
    do {
        ch = getch();
        if (isdigit((unsigned char)ch)) {
            printw("%c", ch);
            k++;
        } else {
            beep();
        }
    } while (k < 2);

    k = 0;
    printw("/____ (YEAR)\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b");
    do {
        ch = getch();
        if (isdigit((unsigned char)ch)) {
            printw("%c", ch);
            k++;
        } else {
            beep();
        }
    } while (k < 4);

    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

Remember to use the "-lncurses" flag when compiling
`gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -o example example.c -lncurses`

Comment: Thanks, its working.. I guess what I was trying to achieve is only be possible by using outside stuffs or some think which is not in standards. Is there any website where I can visit and read everything about non standard stuffs.. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know of a website describing the existing libraries. When you need something specific that is not available in the Standard libraries, you google for that (or ask in StackOverflow) and get the information individually. There are ready-made libraries for almost everything, for example: databases, multi-precision numbers, graphics, compression, audio, ..., ...

Comment: I found a [list of libraries](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/links/libs) on the cppreference site (notably missing *ncurses* hahaha).

Comment: very very Thanks :)